# Not: Command Not Found while setting up a Linode server

Tags: docker, secret-key

So I was working on adding Docker to a linode server, when I got to the step where I had to make a SECRET_KEY_BASE. However, every time I try, it gives me this error:

```
# echo SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(docker-compose --rm web bundle exec rake secret)

/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: Not: command not found
SECRET_KEY_BASE=
```

Please help, the only other solutions on the internet are to install a part of Docker (I have both Docker and Compose) or to not use an ARM-based CPU (which I looked up and saw that Linode uses AMD Zen CPUs)

Comment: Just to be clear the command you are entering does NOT start with `#`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

When I was using this command from the [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04) website to install Docker Compose onto Ubuntu 20.04, I had to add a `v1.29.2` to the version number command

Instead of this:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Use this:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```